# The distribution of the sum of a non-zero vector with random signs

Tags: pr.probability, limit-theorems

Given a non-zero high-dimensional vector, $v\in (\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}) ^ d$, and a random sign vector $s \in \{-1,1\}^d$ (i.e., each entry is a rademacher random variable).

Empirically, I find that the distribution of $s \cdot v$ seems to be $\mathcal{N}(0, \frac{||v||_2^2}{d})$, or at least I can' find an example when it isn't as $d \to \infty $.

(If I would have added that the coordinates are independent and iid, this would be just the Central Limit Theorem.)

Is there some known form of CLT that explains why this would work for a general vector multiplied by random signs?
(or a counterexample that I'm missing)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, your empirically motivated conjecture will not hold in general. E.g., it will not hold if $v_1^2$ is much greater than $\sum_{i\ge2}v_i^2$, where the $v_i$'s are the coordinates of $v$.

On the other hand, by (say) the [Berry--Esseen inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem#Non-identically_distributed_summands), the dot product $s\cdot v$ of $s$ and $v$ will be approximately normal if $\sum_i|v_i|^3$ is much less than $(\sum_i v_i^2)^{3/2}$, which will in turn follow if e.g. $\max_i v_i^2$ is much less than $\sum_i v_i^2$. (I guess the condition that $\sum_i|v_i|^3$ is much less than $(\sum_i v_i^2)^{3/2}$ held in your empirical studies.)

Comment: Hey thanks! do you know of additional formulations of sufficient conditions? I'm looking for an accurate measure, something like a bound on the Skewness of or variance of the coordinates of v.

Barry-Esseen seems to relate independent variables, I'm not sure how to adapt it to the independent case.

Comment: When one says "a random sign vector $s \in \{-1,1\}^d$", it usually means that the vector is uniformly distributed and hence the coordinates are independent. In your empirical studies, how did you produce $s$ and $v$?

Comment: s is uniform as you say. v can be something like pixel intensity of an image, a gradient, or a word embedding (in the autoencoders sense)(so coordinates are depended on each other). I also experimented with a mixture of normal and lognormal samples.

Comment: @AmitPortnoy : As I wrote before, if $s$ is uniform, then the coordinates of $s$ are independent -- so, no problem there. As for the $v$'s you have tried, I would suggest checking for them the condition that $\sum_i|v_i|^3$ is much less than $(\sum_i v_i^2)^{3/2}$ -- I am pretty sure that that will be the case.

Comment: $s \cdot v$ is independent? The condition is kind of the case, but I'm trying to find a more accurate numeric formulation for "much less" (does not have to relate to this specific condition, anything the I can verify easily given a real vector d)

Comment: @AmitPortnoy : What does your question "$s\cdot v$ is independent" mean? $s\cdot v$ is just one random variable. As for the Berry--Esseen inequality, it is quite specific: $|P(s\cdot v\le t)-\Phi(t/(\sum_i v_i^2)^{1/2})|\le0.56 \sum_i|v_i|^3/(\sum_i v_i^2)^{3/2}$ for all real $t$, where $\Phi$ is the standard normal cdf.

Comment: I meant that $s_i \cdot v_i$ are uncorrelated but possibly dependent (between different i's), so I'm not if berry Essen holds here

Comment: @AmitPortnoy : The $s_iv_i$'s are independent, because the $s_i$'s are independent and the $v_i$'s are just given numbers.

Comment: @AmitPortnoy, the more accurate version of this answer is the Berry-Esseen theorem; it’s rude to ask so many questions without showing any sign of following the link provided.

Comment: I did follow the link. I guess I wasn't clear about my view of $v$. Anyway, I do greatly thank and appreciate @Iosif responses which really helped me better understand my problem.

Comment: @AmitPortnoy : By the Berry--Esseen inequality, the distribution of $s\cdot v/(\sum_i v_i^2)^{1/2}$ will converge to the standard normal distribution if $\sum_i|v_i|^3/(\sum_i v_i^2)^{3/2}\to0$. On the other hand, if $\sum_i|v_i|^3/(\sum_i v_i^2)^{3/2}\not\to0$, then the distribution of $s\cdot v/(\sum_i v_i^2)^{1/2}$ will not converge to any normal distribution, because then 
$\max_i v_i^2/\sum_i v_i^2\not\to0$. I recommend seriously studying the book by Petrov https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-65809-9 .

Comment: Previous comment continued: My papers on linear combinations of independent Rademacher random variables and references there may also be helpful.

Comment: Thank you! I took me a few reads to fully grasp how Berry-Esseen applies here. I also went over your theorem from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.2137v2.pdf, which seems particularly useful. thank you again!

Comment: @AmitPortnoy : I am glad to hear this helped.